# Widget title not showing up in my custom WordPress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

I have created a custom theme in my WordPress install. I have added sidebar in it.

My code for adding the sidebar is

In functions.php

```
    function my_register_sidebars() {
    /* Register the 'right' sidebar. */
    register_sidebar(
        array(
            'id'            => 'primary-right',
            'name'          => __( 'Primary Right Sidebar' ),
            'description'   => __( 'Right Side bar' ),
            'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget'  => '</div>',
            'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title'   => '</h3>',
        )
    );
  }
  add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_register_sidebars' );
```

In sidebar.php

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
       <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'primary-right' ); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I am adding widget in this sidebar, the title of widget is not showing up. Please guide where I am wrong.

I am using WordPress 5.8.1

Comment: It usually show it automatically. Could you check the CSS by inspect? If you see this, delete it:   .widgettitle {  display: none; }

Answer (score 1):

for fix this problem, put the following code in function.php of your theme:

```
add_filter('use_widgets_block_editor', '__return_false');
```

Comment: It's works for me but is it the only way , e.g. in case the user changed the  theme ?

Comment: Must be in the function.php file

Comment: Alright, off-topic, can I ask you how such theme(builder works) [screenshot](https://i.redd.it/ikxi3jecsnj81.jpg)  `This is drag and drop them builder `